# MVC Cannot access API Controller actions

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, api

I am currently unable to access my api controller actions. I have an MVC app which calls the api through ajax calls in my javascript.

My API method is:

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/Communication/AddLink")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddLink([FromBody]int id)
{
    //DO STUFF
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnData);
}
```

my ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
     cache: false,
     url: serviceEndpoint + 'api/Communication/AddLink',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { id: commid },
     headers:{
           Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
     },
     success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
     }
 });
```

I retrieve my token as follows:

```
public async static Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenAsync(AuthenticationContext ctx, string resourceId)
{
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(OfficeSettings.ClientId, OfficeSettings.ClientSecret);
    var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    UserIdentifier ident = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);

    var redirectUrl = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await ctx.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceId, credential, ident);
        //var result = await ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, credential);
        LastAuthority = ctx.Authority;
        return result;
     }
     catch (AdalException e)
     {
         logger.Error(e, "AcquireTokenSilentAsync: " + e.Message);
         ctx.TokenCache.Clear();
         return null;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
}
```

and here is my routing from my WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        // DI Config
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        /// Register Types
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
    }
```

This works in fiddler if i add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to my API action but doesnt work inside the app however for obvious reasons this is not a solution.

When i attempt it through fiddler i get the error:

```
IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as i am out of ideas on this one. I am happy to provide further code and info if needed.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

A little additional info. My Api is set to start at localhost:44391 however when its loaded the url is https://localhost:44391/Error/GenericError. Does this possibly indicate something has gone wrong on start up? If so how do i debug this correctly?

Comment: You aren't posting to the right url.  Your route is defined as `api/Communication/AddLink`.  But you're posting to `api/Communication/AddLink/{id}`.

Comment: @Amy apologies that was from an old version, the url has now changed and i will update now

Comment: @ssimeonov i have had a look but im not sure i understand could you elaborate

Comment: I dont understand how that relates to my issue

Comment: Don't worry, I don't understand how it relates, either.